# Something costs memory in this method

Tags: memory-leaks, arduino

I have this method running repeatedly in Arduino loop(), I measure free SRAM before and after.

```
void assignIpAddress(char* inputString) {
    char delims[] = ".";
    char* result = NULL;
    int a = 0;
    char* tempstr = calloc(strlen(inputString)+1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(tempstr, inputString);
    result = strtok(tempstr, delims);
    NetworkSettings.ipAddress[a] = byte(atoi(result));
    while (result != NULL) {
        a++;
        result = strtok(NULL, delims);
        if (result != 0) {
            NetworkSettings.ipAddress[a] = byte(atoi(result));
        }
    }
}
```

I am not well versed in C++, I would need help how can I make this method not cost memory every time it runs.

Thank you.

Comment: You have a `calloc` – and now `free` for – though if doing raw memory management at all, C++ would rather use `new[]` and `delete[]`, which again is outdated, though, modern C++ uses smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: This code looks like C rather than C++.

Comment: Why are you using `char*` instead of `std::string` here anyway? If this is C, then remove the C++ tag and add C. If it's C++, then use C++ features.

Comment: Any reason for implementing your own conversion (that might write beyond `ipAddress` bounds if there are too many dots in the string, by the way) instead of using e.g. [`inet_addr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr) (assuming you can ignore the -1 problem, see there)?

Comment: **If** C++ then you should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`). In any case you should consider const-correctness; you explicitly *copy* `inputString` for not having to modify it, so you should accept a `char const*` pointer (if not switching type anyway).

Comment: @ChrisMM Well, apart from that it should be `char const*` – accepting such a pointer *can* be meaningful even in C++ – this allows to interfere with C-API or using the `char*`s from `int main(...)` directly without having to copy first (implicitly within `std::string`).

Comment: Just noticing, inet_addr might not be available on Arduino, but then have a look at [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/68540/convert-string-to-ipaddress).

Comment: @Aconcagua, as a parameter to the function, sure, I do that too, but throughout it? This code is much simpler using `std::string`

Comment: @ChrisMM Well, still copies, and if short string optimisation fails we have a dynamic allocation. I'd actually avoid that *entirely* on a MCU! If indeed doing the parsing manually I'd look up the periods with `strchr` and parse the resulting substrings via [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) instead (provided that's available on Arduino at all – which standard do they support nowadays?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem of your function is that you dynamically allocate memory via `calloc` without `free`-ing it again – do so before exiting (`free(tmpstr);`) and the memory leak is fixed.

*However* there are further issues. At very first you intend not to modify the input string – that's why you create a copy at all, isn't it? Maybe you want to be able to pass string literals to. Then you should accept the value by a pointer to const: `char`  **`const`** `* inputString`!

Then do not reinvent the wheel; apparently, there's an `IPAdress::fromString` function (see [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/68540/convert-string-to-ipaddress), [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/IPAddress.h) or [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-manipulate-ipaddress-variables-convert-to-string/222693%5D)), though unfortunately that's not officially [documented](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/ethernet/ipaddress/). If indeed existing, use this one.

Otherwise – as on a micro-controller (Arduino) – avoid dynamic memory allocation *entrirely*! Admitted, you cannot use `strtok` then any more, but you can do this just as easily and even more efficiently by using [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) instead to parse the individual numbers; this avoids all the problems you have so far: needing to create a copy and iterating twice (once for finding the period, once for converting):

```cpp
for(;;)
{
    if(a >= std::size(NetworkSettings.ipAddress)
    {
        // too many periods! -> invalid IP address
        return false; // introducing a new return value
                      // so that you can check outside
    }

    // note that the following strtoul skips whitespace at the beginning of the
    // string; if you do NOT want to accept you need to check explicitly:
    if(isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*inputString))
        return false;
    // but that's optional...

    char* end; // note: strtoul requires non-const; still don't ever modify
               // *end as inputString is pointer to const!
                
    unsigned long value = strtoul(inputString, &end, 10);

    // on the other hand IF you accept whitespace at the beginning you might
    // as well want to accept at the end, then simply skip the whitespace:
    while(isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*end)))
        ++end;
    // again optional; recommended to opt for exactly one of both...

    if(value > 255) || (*end != 0 && *end != '.'))
    {
        // invalid value!
        return false;
    }
    NetworkSettings.ipAddress[a] = value;
    if(*end == 0)
    {
        // we are done!
        return true;
    }

    inputString = end + 1;
    ++a;
}
```

This is fine as `strtoul` stops parsing at the first character it cannot interpret any more, which should be in our case either the period or the end of the string – and if a negative value is included it is converted to a value larger than 255 which again is fine for us.

Note that this is entirely untested code, if you find a bug please fix yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes according to your advice. Everything works as intended, I understand the problem better now.